# Can this statement be called a paradox?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

The sentence is:

> She needs her glasses to find her glasses.

The inference that she doesn't have her glasses and she needs her glasses to find her glasses somehow sounds paradoxical, but is it really paradoxical? If not, is there a term that can be used to describe the seeming contradiction?

Comment: The paradox is: you can call ***anything*** a paradox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 'irony' is the figure of speech that fits that particular circumstance, not 'paradox'.  'Irony' is used in various senses, but this is a very direct one, in which there is a frustrated connection between something desired and one's ability to have it.

Classically the 'sirens', of Greek mythology, presented sailors with the most bitter irony. These most desirable creatures in life were also dangerous.  How often is that the case ! If it is lovely, it is usually illegal, immoral or it makes you fat!

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a [Catch-22](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_%28logic%29), which is a kind of paradox. From WP:

> A catch-22 is a paradoxical situation from which an individual cannot escape because of contradictory rules.

The rules are thus: She needs her glasses to find her glasses, but she can't use her glasses if she can't find them. Catch-22.

Answer (score 2):

I would say so.

[Lanham's](http://www.bookfinder.com/search/?ac=sl&st=sl&ref=bf_s2_a1_t1_1&qi=gtmGigEVY2NTL38gxPTgBD8bc9k_6571608522_1:82:641&bq=author=richard%2520a.%2520lanham&title=handlist%2520of%2520rhetorical%2520terms) definition of paradox is 'A seemingly self-contradictory statement, which yet is shown to be (sometimes in a surprising way) true: "She makes the black night bright by smiling on it." - see also Oxymoron [a pairing of opposites].

The only other potential candidate I can think of is [Syncrisis](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/S/syncrisis.htm), for which [Lanham](http://www.bookfinder.com/search/?ac=sl&st=sl&ref=bf_s2_a1_t1_1&qi=gtmGigEVY2NTL38gxPTgBD8bc9k_6571608522_1:82:641&bq=author=richard%2520a.%2520lanham&title=handlist%2520of%2520rhetorical%2520terms) gives (among others) an example from Julius Caesar: 'Cowards die many times before their deaths; / The valiant never taste of death but once.'

Your example also includes Epistrophe (repetition of 'her glasses' in final position).

I'm trying to think whether it could be made into a Chiasmus (a-b,notb-nota) form, eg 'Despised if ugly; if she's fair, betrayed.' (Mary Leapor - Essay on women).

Comment: Your answer is a good one. But I am more satisfied with the suggestion of 'irony'.